# Seeking documentation for Netezza Spatial Functions?

Tags: documentation

I am looking for some documentation or manual or reference guide for Netezza Spatial Functions.

Any idea where can I get the same?

Comment: Are you using [Netezza with ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v00000013000000)?

Comment: Short answer is no I have found that Netezza has added spatial data and functions so I would like to go though that and what ever I have created in my python script using arcpy that I can migrate to Netezza using spatial functions. So I am looking for the functions documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The Netezza Spatial documentation that I use was included in the download from the IBM\Netezza portal\ftp site.

As in, along with the nz-analytics-v2.0.3 download, there are nz-analyticsdoc-v2.0.3 and nz-analyticsdochtml-v2.0.3 downloads.

Unpackaging nz-analyticsdoc-v2.0.3, you'll find two pdfs:
Netezza_Spatial_Package_Reference_Guide-2.0.3.pdf
Netezza_Spatial_Package_Users_Guide.pdf

I've never found them online.

I would talk to whoever maintains your Netezza Appliance, or failing that, an IBM rep.